# Getting started creating LEGO kinetic sculptures

Tags: technic, building, motor, moc

I’m brand new here and fairly new to LEGO. I’m an adult artist who wants to make LEGO-based kinetic sculptures. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

My experience is very limited — as a child raised in the “dark ages,” I was forbidden from owning or playing with LEGO because I was female (though I used to beg my parents for them, LOL). So I’ve only built a few sets recently, mostly architectural and for display. I’ve been watching videos, and reading a few LEGO idea books, but not finding a lot of info on Technic, though I did build a Mindstorms robotics set back in the 2000’s. And I’m not real interested in building cars, though I suppose I do need Technics pieces. Now I’m considering getting some of the new Technics space sets for 2024, though.

Thoughts on how I should proceed to making my first kinetic sculpture?

(I hope I asked this question the right way. It’s my first one.)

Comment: Great advice from Alex which I’m already following up on. TYSM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are interested in kinetic sculptures, as you have already figured out, you would need Technic elements, mostly. While it is possible to use non-Technic elements to build moving contraptions, Technic system is designed for  dynamic models and for increased model rigidity.

General advice on learning new techniques is just either building sets you are interested in or other people's MOCs (My Own Creations). For later I suggest checking [Rebrickable](https://rebrickable.com) - it is also a great website for inspiration. While you can get general understanding of Technic system by reading some literature you need to know your elements, their physical properties, geometry, how they interact and what kind of result you could get combining several of them together. For this you may want to get yourself familiar with a variety of Technic elements - you can find them listed in [Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogTree.asp?itemType=P) catalog under "Technic" categories. This is one of the major places where you can acquire individual parts for your own models too.

I know you mentioned you don't like building cars, but these sets usually contain the greatest variety of moving elements you cannot find in more "static" models. Bigger sets are great "part-packs" as they help out with getting yourself a decent amount of parts of different sizes and shapes. While brand new stuff is great, Technic sets are pretty robust so you may look for older models in used condition, to save some money for more LEGO.

Comment: Thank you, Alex. I’m following your suggestions.   I was wondering about buying one or two of the Technic educational kits as well? I noticed they look pretty pricey. How useful do you think they would be compared to just buying a couple of technic models, especially for an adult?

Comment: @ShyPlatypus all sets may be useful, but I find LEGO Education sets to be overpriced for what they offer. Don't quote me on this, but I think I have read somewhere the cost of teaching programme is included in the price of these sets. I, personally, have lots of Technic sets and none of Education ones.

Comment: Tysm. I appreciate your answers so much! @Alex